# Retrieve FF in 'Normal Mode'

Tags: firefox

My Firefox window opens in 'Private Mode' by default (I must have used a trick in past for that. But now, I forgot what was that!). Some sites aren't accessible in private mode. For them, I want to use the Normal Mode. How to retrieve it?

PS: ~/.config/autostart shows 'Exec=firefox %u'

Comment: "always use private mode" is done through the history settings in firefox, "use custom settings for history" and then select "always use private mode". while this is set, you can't open regular windows. you will have to undo it in firefox settings and find some other way to always use private mode (such as adding `-private` to shortcuts, etc)

Comment: >Esther, it worked. Thanks.